# Concrete practical examples for discrete time markov chain with transition rewards

Tags: markov-chains

Can anyone show examples for discrete-time markov chains with associated transition rewards?

I am searching for examples of industrial usage of markov chains where their expect and variance or covariance of accumulated rewards until reaching some goal state subset are of practical interest.

I am searching for examples as concrete as possible, in the optimal case i.e. a concrete markov chain or a series of markov chains, so that I can run special algorithms (calculating variances/ covariances) on them in order to measure runtime of these algorithms.